# @ActiveProfiles annotation doesn't work after I upgrade my springboot to version 2.4.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

Previously our application was based on springboot version 2.2.2, and one of our test was using `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to overwrite `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` property configuration from our `application.xml` file. Everything worked perfectly.

```
spring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:}
```

However after we upgraded our springboot to version 2.4.2, it doesn't work any more, we can only read **spring.profiles.active** as a empty string in our test, but previously it could be read as string "test".

What should I do to make @ActiveProfiles annotation work in the version of 2.4.2 of springboot? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are being affected by the fix for [Spring Boot issue 19537](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19537). In order to fix support profiles with commas in their name, the active profiles are now set as individual indexed properties. For example, if you activate the profiles `a`, `b,c`, and `d`, three properties will be set:

1. `spring.profiles.active[0]=a`
2. `spring.profiles.active[1]=b,c`
3. `spring.profiles.active[2]=d`

Prior to this fix, `spring.profiles.active` would be set to `a,b,c,d` which would result in 4 profiles being active: `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

I would recommend that you review the code where you're reviewing the `spring.profiles.active` property. Accessing the property's value directly is rather unusual. A more typical approach is to call `getActiveProfiles()` on the `Environment`.